# Reading datypes correctly by PHP from Postgres

Tags: php, string, postgresql, types, integer

**How do you compile integer data in Postgres by PHP?**

My integers are string as the following show by `var_dump ( $_SESSION )`

```
  'logged_in' => int 1
  'user_id' => string '9' (length=1)                 // should be int
  'a_moderator' => string '0' (length=1)             // should be int
```

I compile the values by the following code which obviously is the source of the problem after `pg_prepare` and `pg_execute`.

```
    while ( $row = pg_fetch_array( $result ) ) { 
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert strings to integers using  [intval](http://www.php.net/intval):

```
$str = "5";
$num = intval($str);
```

or by type coercion:

```
$str = "5";
$num = (int) $str;

//this works too
$num = (integer) $str;
```

some test code:

```
<?php
   $str = "10";
   $num = intval($str);
   //$num = (int)$str;
 
   if ($str === 10) echo "String";
   if ($num === 10) echo "Integer";
?>
```

Further reading:

[Type Jugging](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 4):

It's ordinary for PHP database extensions to return all data types as string, because some SQL data types cannot be represented in PHP native data types.

Example:  PostgreSQL `BIGINT` (8-byte integer data type) would overflow the `int` PHP type (unless PHP is compiled with 64-bit support), and be cast as `float` which might lose exactness.