# How to make pgsql driver to return integer values?

Tags: php, postgresql

Currently all the values returned by pgsql driver in my setup are strings.

Consider this:

```
$res = pg_fetch_all("select 1::int as id;");
```

The result is:

```
var_dump($res)  
array(1) {  
'id' => string(1) "1"  
}
```

Is there a way to make php5-pgsql driver to return integer values?
I will hate to have to convert all the output fields to integers manually.
Also I prefer not to use the PDO driver.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314986/reading-datypes-correctly-by-php-from-postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-field-type.php

Now the way I would go about this is loop through the fields and coerce them to related types.  This is something you should probably do in a basic wrapper (some sort of database abstraction layer).

In short you can't make the pgsql driver do this but you can create wrappers which do it yourself.